# Find lower angle

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, area

I'm solving this integral
$$\iint_Dxy \,dA$$
where
$$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\,/\,x^2+y^2\leq1,\,y\leq\sqrt3x\}$$

From the plot I know it is a circumference and a line

I'm switching to polar coordinates, however I'm not sure how to find the angle of $\theta$

$$\begin{aligned} r\sin\theta&=\sqrt3r\cos\theta \\ \tan\theta&=\sqrt3\\\theta&=\frac{\pi}{3}\end{aligned}$$

I know this is my upper bound from $\theta$ but how do I find my lower bound?

$$? \leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: The line has an angle $\pi$, then the angle is $-(\pi -\pi/3)=-2\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line has an angle $\pi$, then the angle is $−(\pi−\pi/3)=−2\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

The given integral is clearly zero. $D$ is given by half a circle, i.e. a domain admitting a (polar) parametrization with $\theta\in[a,a+\pi]$ and $\rho\in[0,1]$. Switching to polar coordinates

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{a}^{a+\pi}\rho^3 \sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta \,d\rho = \frac{1}{8}\int_{a}^{a+\pi}\sin(2\theta)\,d\theta=0$$
since the integral of a sine function over a full period equals zero: $a$ is irrelevant.